# cannot exit from long result

Tags: powershell, enter

When using PowerShell with a result that is more than the active window, it will continue the page until the [END]. However I cannot seem to stop this. The next time I press enter, it pastes the result in again.

Comment: Sorry, but it's entirely unclear to me what you're asking. Please elaborate. An example/demonstration might be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd rather not speculate.